# Android - Aligning views to the ends of a layout

Tags: android

Sorry if my question sounds simple but I'm working on a simple layout for my list item and my intention align to textviews one on each end of the layout. My attempts are as below but the texviews are right next to each other. Any ideas where I'm going wrong?

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:padding="10dp"
    android:orientation="horizontal">

    <LinearLayout 
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:id="@+id/ll_finc_calctr_result_label"> 

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/tv_finc_calctr_result_label"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"/>

    </LinearLayout>

    <LinearLayout 
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_gravity="right"
        android:layout_alignRight="@+id/ll_finc_calctr_result_label"
        android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
        android:layout_toRightOf="@+id/ll_finc_calctr_result_label">

           <TextView
               android:id="@+id/tv_finc_calctr_result"
               android:layout_width="wrap_content"
               android:layout_height="wrap_content"
               android:layout_gravity="center"/>

    </LinearLayout>

</RelativeLayout>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this..

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:orientation="horizontal"
    android:padding="10dp" >

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/tv_finc_calctr_result_label"
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_weight="1"
        android:gravity="left"
        android:text="text left" />

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/tv_finc_calctr_result"
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_weight="1"
        android:gravity="right"
        android:text="text right" />

</LinearLayout>
```

Answer (score 0):

Firstly, you need to remove the two properties of `alignRight` and `toRightOf` from the second linear layout:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:padding="10dp"
    android:orientation="horizontal">

    <LinearLayout 
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:id="@+id/ll_finc_calctr_result_label"> 

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/tv_finc_calctr_result_label"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:text="ss"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"/>

    </LinearLayout>

    <LinearLayout 
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_gravity="right"
        android:layout_alignParentRight="true" >

           <TextView
               android:id="@+id/tv_finc_calctr_result"
               android:layout_width="wrap_content"
               android:layout_height="wrap_content"
               android:text="sse"
               android:layout_gravity="center"/>

    </LinearLayout>

</RelativeLayout>
```

Which will result in the second textview on right side.

And I would advise that you don't take two linear layout as both of them contain just a single textview:

Something like:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:orientation="horizontal"
    android:padding="10dp" >

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/tv_finc_calctr_result_label"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="ss" />

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/tv_finc_calctr_result"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
        android:text="sse" />

</RelativeLayout>
```

Output:

[image]

Comment: Thanks for the reply. Your reply seems to work for me on some layouts and it fails on others. It must be my fault with how I placing the relativelayout. I'll look deeper into my logic. Thanks though !!!

Answer (score 0):

The solution provided by Hariharan is excellent. Another option might be more useful if you need the textViews' width to actually be wrap_content (for instance if they have a background styling, etc.) You can achieve a more accurate behavior using a space:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="wrap_content"
android:orientation="horizontal"
android:padding="10dp" >

<TextView
    android:id="@+id/tv_finc_calctr_result_label"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content" />

<Space
    android:layout_width="0dp"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:layout_weight="1" />

<TextView
    android:id="@+id/tv_finc_calctr_result"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_gravity="center" />

</LinearLayout>
```

Comment: cheers for the suggestion but as you say Hariharan's suggestion is very god and it works for me. thanks.